# javascript multidimensional objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following requirements that needs to be build in javascript objects/array. Can anyone help me with a sample?

**Requirements**

1. Start with invoices number. Key: `invoice`, Value: `INV001`, `INV002`, `INV003`...
2. Each invoice number contain 1 or more receipt number. 1 receipt number may belongs to 1 or more invoices number. Key: `receipt`, Value: `RCP001`, `RCP002`, `RCP003`...
3. Each receipt number contain 1 or more payment method. Key: `payment`, Value: `cash`, `cc`, `ibg`, `chq`...
4. Each payment method contain only 1 amount. Key: `amount`, Value: `5`, `10`, `1000`, `9999`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't **inherently** support multidimensional `arrays`.

Instead, You need to create an `array` of `arrays`.  IE

Start with your 3 primary arrays:

```
var invoiceArr = ["invoice1", "invoice2", "invoice3"];
var receiptArr = ["receipt1", "receipt2", "receipt3"];
var paymentArr = ["payment1", "payment2", "payment3"];
```

Add them to a main array:

```
var mainArray = [invoiceArr, receiptArr, paymentArr];
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to follow the below code or do you need further instructions?

```
   var solution = {
        invoice: [{"INV1" : { receipt : ["RCP1" : { payment : ["cash"  , "cc"]
                                                 } , "RCP2"]
                           }}, 
                  {"INV2" : { receipt : ["RCP1", "RCP2"]
                           }}
                 ],

    }
```

Comment: Some extra objects that you missed in the heirarchy. I don't understand the point of this question.

Comment: I just wanted to show a principal and not deliver the solution